# Remove Decimal places from Currency?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have the following example:

```
// Currencies

var price: Double = 3.20
println("price: \(price)")

let numberFormater = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormater.locale = locale
numberFormater.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
numberFormater.maximumFractionDigits = 2
```

I want to have the currency output with 2 digests. In case the currency digests are all zero I want that they will not be displayed. So 3,00 should be displayed as: `3`. All other values should be displayed with the two digests.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: If you are dealing with currency you should use `NSDecimalNumber` not `double` because double can not represent all the needed values exactly. From the docs: NSDecimalNumber, an immutable subclass of NSNumber, provides an object-oriented wrapper for doing base 10 arithmetic. the double 1.01 can not be represented exactly it is : 1.01000000000000000888. That small error is meaningful in comparisons among other issues.

Comment: You could create a variable called `roundedPrice` by rounding the `price` to the nearest whole number and then applying 2 decimal places to `roundedPrice`. Then, if `price == roundedPrice`, `numberFormater.maximumFractionDigits = 0`, else, `= 2`. That's just some pseudocode off the top of my head, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: @zaph Can I convert Double to NSDecimalNumber

Comment: No, not all decimal numbers are also valid `NSDecimal` numbers. `NSDecimal` numbers are generally created from stings such as one would obtain from user input in text field with `decimalNumberWithString:`. The point is that a double should never be created in the first place. Using decimal numbers is a matter of correctness and generally used when decimal numbers are needed to mirror the real works such as monetary transactions. If monetary transactions are being calculated and they must be correct then decimal numbers should be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `numberStyle` to `.decimal` style to be able to set `minimumFractionDigits` property depending if the floating point is even or not:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var isWholeNumber: Bool { isZero ? true : !isNormal ? false : self == rounded() }
}
```

---

You can also extend Formatter and create static formatters to avoid creating the formatters more than once when running your code:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let currency: NumberFormatter = {
        let numberFormater = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormater.numberStyle = .currency
        return numberFormater
    }()
    static let currencyNoSymbol: NumberFormatter = {
        let numberFormater = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormater.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormater.currencySymbol = ""
        return numberFormater
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var currencyFormatted: String {
        Formatter.currency.minimumFractionDigits = isWholeNumber ? 0 : 2
        return Formatter.currency.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
    var currencyNoSymbolFormatted: String {
        Formatter.currencyNoSymbol.minimumFractionDigits = isWholeNumber ? 0 : 2
        return Formatter.currencyNoSymbol.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
3.0.currencyFormatted            // "$3"
3.12.currencyFormatted           // "$3.12"
3.2.currencyFormatted            // "$3.20"

3.0.currencyNoSymbolFormatted    // "3"
3.12.currencyNoSymbolFormatted   // "3.12"
3.2.currencyNoSymbolFormatted    // "3.20"

let price = 3.2
print("price: \(price.currencyFormatted)")  // "price: $3.20\n"
```

Comment: But if I do not use NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle I do not get the currency symbol

Comment: You can add it using string interpolation

Comment: You can also check if the string has suffix ",00" or ".00" and if true delete last 3 characters

Comment: Is there a way to strip the currency symbol

Comment: You cannot simply search for a suffix of ",00" of ".00" since in many locales there is something after the number portion. For example, someone in France running `3.0.currency` will result in `3,00 €`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NSNumberFormatter you can just use NSString init(format: arguments:)

`var string = NSString(format:@"%.2g" arguments:price)`

I'm not good with swift, but this should work.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

Comment: @zaph like in which cases?

Comment: The general problem is not with the formatting but the use of floating point numbers where a series of calculations, each which should be a decimal number is a little off because the actual number can not be represented accurately such as 1.33. Those small errors can and in reality do compound so that they will round up when displayed and cause an error. The point is ti use decimal numbers when necessary such as in monetary calculations where 3 mils become a full cent. Just rounding the final result is not sufficient. I wrote my sample calculator with `NSDecimalNumber`, it was not difficult.

Comment: In any case the format `%.2g` is probably not what the OP wants since it will produce results such as: "1.3e+02". Instead probably `%.2f` is more what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  extension Double {
    var currencyFormatted: String {
      var isWholeNumber: Bool { isZero ? true : !isNormal ? false : self == rounded() }
      let formatter = NumberFormatter()
      formatter.numberStyle = .currency
      formatter.minimumFractionDigits = isWholeNumber ? 0 : 2
      return formatter.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
  }
```