# Rounding numbers in swift

Tags: swift, rounding

In Swift, I need to be able to round numbers based on their value. If a number is whole, which just ".0" after it, I need to convert it to an integer, and if the number has digits after the decimal that is greater than 2 digits, I need to round it to 2 digits.

For example:

```
1.369352 --> 1.37
7.75     --> 7.75  
2.0      --> 2
```

How can I check my numbers and round them according to these rules?

Comment: 1.369352 is not rounded to 1.36 it is rounded to 1.37. Which do you want? 1.36 or 1.37?

Comment: Also, do you just want to display them at 2 decimal places? Or is it vitally important to also store them at 2 decimal places?

Comment: @Fogmeister Yea that was my bad, I just put in random numbers following 1.36 without thinking about it. Also, the app I'm making is rounding seconds so 2 decimal places is preferred

Comment: Ah ok :) you might want to update your question anyway. It makes a good example to use 1.37 :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Decimal places from Currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947017/remove-decimal-places-from-currency)

Comment: Is it ok to return the string representation of the numbers? if not, how do you want the return value formatted, as there is no way to sometimes return an int, and other times a double/float from the same function. (it could also be set up return both an int and string, with one set to a default value (eg 0 or -1)). which way do you prefer?

Comment: @PatrickL Yes, returning them as strings is fine, they're just being added to a label so that is actually preferred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should be good?

```
func formatNumber (number: Double) -> String? {

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    let formattedNumberString = formatter.stringFromNumber(number)
    return formattedNumberString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".00", withString: "")

}

formatNumber(3.25) // 3.25
formatNumber(3.00) // 3
formatNumber(3.25678) // 3.26
```

Comment: Good use of the number for matter. You might want to check the decimal delimiter though as it may not always be a period point.

Answer (score 1):

this function returns a string of the result needed.

```
func roundnumber(roundinput:Double) ->String{
var roundoutputint=0
var roundoutputfloat=0.0
if (roundinput - floor(roundinput) < 0.00001) { // 0.000001 can be changed depending on the level of precision you need
    //integer

    roundoutputint = Int(round(roundinput))
    return String(roundoutputint)
}
else {
    //not integer
    //roundoutputfloat=round(10 * roundinput) / 10
    return String(format:"%.2f",roundinput)
}
}
```

for example:

```
roundnumber(1.3693434) //returns "1.37"
roundnumber(7.75)     //returns "7.75"
roundnumber(2.0)      // returns "2"
```